# jQuery - mouseenter / mouseleave with timer not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, mouseenter

What I am trying to do is only run my code when someone has hovered on an element for 1 second.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
var timer;

$(".homeLinkWrap").mouseenter(function() {
  timer = setTimeout(function(){
   $(this).find('.homeLinkNfo').removeClass('flipOutY').addClass('flipInY').css({opacity: '1'});
    console.log('in');
  }, 1000);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find('.homeLinkNfo').removeClass('flipInY').addClass('flipOutY');
    console.log('out');
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

The first part (mouseenter) IS NOT functioning and DOESN'T remove the class and then add the new one. The second one (mouseleave) IS functioning properly and DOES remove the class and add the new one.

I am guessing it is because I am targeting $(this) which is the current element being hovered over and since it is in a timer function jQuery doesn't know which element $(this) is referring to.

What can I do to remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you are calling $(this) inside the setTimeout function.  You need to do something like this:

```
$(".homeLinkWrap").mouseenter(function() {
    var $self = $(this);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
       $self.find('.homeLinkNfo').removeClass('flipOutY').addClass('flipInY').css({opacity: '1'});
       console.log('in');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `setTimeout` callback, `this` no longer refers to the jQuery selection. You should either keep a reference to the selection:

```
$(".homeLinkWrap").mouseenter(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  timer = setTimeout(function(){
     $this.find('.homeLinkNfo').removeClass('flipOutY').addClass('flipInY').css({opacity: '1'});
    console.log('in');
  }, 1000);
})
```

Or use an arrow function (ES2015)

```
$(".homeLinkWrap").mouseenter(function() {
  timer = setTimeout(() => {
   $(this).find('.homeLinkNfo').removeClass('flipOutY').addClass('flipInY').css({opacity: '1'});
    console.log('in');
  }, 1000);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `this` inside the callback function that you're passing to `setTimeout` doesn't reference to the same point that the `this` outside the callback does.

There are some ways of solving your problem, I'll suggest you to use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind your callback function to the same `this` you have outside:

```js
var timer;

$(".homeLinkWrap").mouseenter(function() {
  timer = setTimeout((function() {
    $(this).find('.homeLinkNfo').removeClass('flipOutY').addClass('flipInY').css({ opacity: '1' });
  }).bind(this), 1000);
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).find('.homeLinkNfo').removeClass('flipInY').addClass('flipOutY');
  clearTimeout(timer);
});
```